# Mac OS Finder - Read File Folder Order/Positions (Arrange By) thru Command Line

Tags: macos, finder, command-line

In the Finder , Arrange -> None provides the ability to specify a custom sort for the files within a folder.

Is there any way to read this info from the command line?  A Mac OS utility equivalent to ls with the ability to get the sort data.

I realize that because of the graphical nature of the Finder folder, this info will be x,y screen coordinates

Ideally I could use this utility to build a shell script or command that returns a sorted list of files (kinda like ls -R and variants)

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain this information using AppleScript, which is, of course, something you can execute from the command line using `osascript`.

Each *Finder* item has an AppleScript property called `position` that stores the `{x, y}`position of the item within its parent window (there’s another property called `bounds` that stores the coordinates that define the bounding rectangle of the item).

```
    tell application "Finder" to get the position of every file in folder "My Folder"
        --> {{40, 199}, {230, 43}, {40, 43}, {40, 121}, {40, 277}, {230, 121}, {267, 184}, {230, 277}, {420, 43}}
```

(*Can you spot the item I moved off its grid-aligned position ?*)

From the command line, you might implement it like this:

```
    osascript -e "tell app \"finder\" to get position of items in folder posix file \"$PWD\""
```

which, for the same folder as above, returns

```
    40, 199, 230, 43, 40, 43, 40, 121, 40, 277, 230, 121, 267, 184, 230, 277, 420, 43
```

For a specific file:

```
    osascript -e "tell app \"finder\" to get position of file \"Self Portrait I.jpg\" in folder posix file \"$PWD\""
        --> 230, 43
```

Answer (score 0):

Icon pos info is stored in .DSStore in a proprietary format .  See perl Mac::Finder::DSStore for reverse engineered documentation